# How do I upgrade React from 0.13 to 15.3.2?

Tags: reactjs, npn

I'm a beginner and I need to upgrade React from 0.13 to 15.3.2 Please tell me the exact procedure.

Comment: While this is a valid question, I've downvoted you because you haven't shown any effort. You might come up with much better questions if you try anything by yourself.

Comment: Duly Noted. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There are actually fewer breaking changes between 0.13 and 15.3.2 than you might think. React jumped straight from version 0.14 to 15.0 so there are actually only two breaking versions between 0.13 and 15.3.2. You best bet is to check out https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/all.html and check the breaking versions to work out what you need to do in order to bring your code up to standard.

Probably the biggest thing that might impact you is the fact that in v0.14 (https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/10/07/react-v0.14.html) the ReactDOM package was split out from the main react package so you'll have to include that in your project separately. That might be a good place to start because it might be the only thing you need to do.